# Can i use a text file instead for ip,ip,ip as a ExitNode? Like ExitNodes torlist.txt

Tags: configuration

Can I use a text file instead for `ip,ip,ip` as a ExitNode? Like `ExitNodes torlist.txt`?

So instead of `Exitnodes ip,ip,ip` I want too use like ... Exitnodes -f toriplist.txt or something

any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to write `exitpolicy filename`. But there are several ways you can go:

1. You can enter your list of IPs as a command line option: `tor -ExitNodes $(cat list_of_ips)`
2. Another way is to create a `torrc` and start Tor with that `torrc`. So assume there is a `torrc.template` and a `list_of_ips`. So you can do something like `cat torrc.template list_of_ips > torrc && tor -f torrc`. Whenever your `list_of_ips` changes you re-create the `torrc` and restart the Tor process (or send a HUP).

Comment: Hmm.. thx for the anwser but i rly don't understand  ^^ My english is really bad so :/ is there any chance i can like do Exitnodes  torips.txt in the torrc settings file ? And copy paste all the tor ips too the torips.txt file so it will Load exitnodes from the torips.txt instead? Sorry for my retardness^^ hah.

Comment: You can't directly use a text file in torrc. It needs to be entered manually in the torrc file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it *directly*, but the exact functionality you want to achieve is just a Python or shell script: using ControlPort and Tor control protocol. You can set desired ExitNodes value from your script running on cron or in a daemon mode. But remember - changes are for a single tor launch session only, i.e. config file is not overwritten automatically every time. And - if you will restart Tor - you will need to re-configure it via ControlPort again. So use either a shellscript(I suggest two, actually: to reconfigure and to forcible reconfigure in case of tor restart detected) or a Python daemon.